# Intercept XMLHttpRequest and modify responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to build a script that will act as a proxy/wrapper for the native `XMLHttpRequest` object enabling me to intercept it, modify the responseText and return back to the original onreadystatechange event.

The context being, if the data the app is trying to receive is already available in local storage, to abort the `XMLHttpRequest` and pass the locally stored data back into the apps success/failure callback methods. Assume I have no control over the apps existing AJAX callback methods.

I had originally tried the following idea..

```
var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data){
   //Do some stuff in here to modify the responseText
   send.call(this, data);
};
```

But as I have now established, the responseText is read only.

I then tried taking a step back, writing my own full native proxy to `XMLHttpRequest`, ultimately ending up writing my own version of the native methods. Similar to what is discussed here...

http://www.ilinsky.com/articles/XMLHttpRequest/#implementation-wrapping

But it rapidly got confusing, and still have the difficulty of returning the modified data back into the original `onReadyStateChange` method.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```js
//
// firefox, ie8+ 
//
var accessor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'responseText');

Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'responseText', {
 get: function() {
  console.log('get responseText');
  return accessor.get.call(this);
 },
 set: function(str) {
  console.log('set responseText: %s', str);
  //return accessor.set.call(this, str);
 },
 configurable: true
});


//
// chrome, safari (accessor == null)
//
var rawOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
 if (!this._hooked) {
  this._hooked = true;
  setupHook(this);
 }
 rawOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}

function setupHook(xhr) {
 function getter() {
  console.log('get responseText');

  delete xhr.responseText;
  var ret = xhr.responseText;
  setup();
  return ret;
 }

 function setter(str) {
  console.log('set responseText: %s', str);
 }

 function setup() {
  Object.defineProperty(xhr, 'responseText', {
   get: getter,
   set: setter,
   configurable: true
  });
 }
 setup();
}
```

Comment: This was overkill for what I needed, but the key takeaway for me was `var rawOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;` and `rawOpen.apply(this, arguments);`, which allowed me to plug in my own override (as you show) but still let the call pass-through as normal so that the caller doesn't know anything different.

Comment: Don't understand why do you `delete xhr.responseText` and then `var ret = xhr.responseText`

Comment: What's the intent of setup() inside of getter() function? I get maximum call stack...

Answer (score 2):

The following script perfectly intercept the data before sending via XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send

```
<script>
(function(send) { 

        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) { 

            this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() { 

            }, false); 

            console.log(data); 
            alert(data); 

        }; 

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
</script>
```

Comment: Also found a great similar solution here: https://medium.com/@gilfink/quick-tip-creating-an-xmlhttprequest-interceptor-1da23cf90b76

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, to intercept the response of `XMLHttpRequest`, a more modern solution will be extending the original XMLHttpRequest and overwrite it in the `window` object:

```js
const { interceptXhrResponse } = (function () {
  let interceptionRules = [];

  /**
   * Function to intercept responses for given URL patterns
   * @param {RegExp} urlPattern - Regular expression to match the (canonicalized) URL
   * @param {Function} responseHandler - Function to handle the intercepted response
   */
  function interceptXhrResponse(urlPattern, responseHandler) {
    interceptionRules.push({ urlPattern, responseHandler });
  }

  // Function to find specific handler for the URL and return modified response
  function handleInterceptedResponse(response, url) {
    const interceptionRule = interceptionRules.find(({ urlPattern }) =>
      urlPattern.test(url)
    );

    if (interceptionRule) {
      const { responseHandler } = interceptionRule;
      return responseHandler(response, url);
    }

    return response;
  }

  const OriginalXMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;

  class XMLHttpRequest extends OriginalXMLHttpRequest {
    get responseText() {
      // If the request is not done, return the original responseText
      if (this.readyState !== 4) {
        return super.responseText;
      }

      return handleInterceptedResponse(super.responseText, this.responseURL);
    }

    get response() {
      // If the request is not done, return the original response
      if (this.readyState !== 4) {
        return super.response;
      }

      return handleInterceptedResponse(super.response, this.responseURL);
    }
  }

  window.XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;

  return { interceptXhrResponse };
})();
```

The upper code exposes the `interceptXhrResponse` function, allowing you to specify a URL pattern with a regular expression and a corresponding response handler. You can return everything you want in the handler to change the response.

For example:

```js
interceptXhrResponse(/.+/, (response, url) => {
  return `Response of ${url}: Intercepted. Original response length: ${String(response).length}`
})
```

Then we can try to initiate an `XMLHttpRequest`:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/404')
xhr.send()
xhr.onloadend = () => {
  console.log(xhr.responseText)
}
```

Output:

```
Response of https://stackoverflow.com/404: Intercepted. Original response length: 63486
```

Answer (score 0):

Your step-back is an overkill: you may add your own getter on XMLHttpRequest: ([more about properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty))

```
Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype,"myResponse",{
  get: function() {
    return this.responseText+"my update"; // anything you want
  }
});
```

the usage:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
console.log(xhr.myResponse); // xhr.responseText+"my update"
```

**Note** on modern browsers you may run `xhr.onload` (see [XMLHttpRequest2 tips](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/))

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using this idea, but I need xhr.responseText to be changed. By adding the new value, 'myResponse', would mean having to change the app code in the onReadyStateChange event to use .myResponse rather than .responseText.