# how to intercept all http requests in angular

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular8, angular-http-interceptors, angular-service-worker

i m creating a WPA using angular 8

yesterday i read about service workers and also implemented them in plain javascript. they worked well and gave me full access over all network requests

but today when i implemented service workes in angular 8
i got to know they can only intercept http calls made by httclient [not so helpful]

what i want is even if i try to do a get request using jquery directly from console i should get a note

and yesterday i could do it with plain js implementation

this doubt is not realed to coding at all

> all i want to know is : is there a way to get low level access to the
>   fetch requests of service worker ? or will i have give up the idea of
>   httpInterceptor and implement my own logic using plain js ?

please help
any kind of arguments are welcomed

Comment: You should be using @angular/pwa see https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Comment: @TomShaw thats what i m using

Comment: it just let me implement http interceptor rest of the things are handled by itself

Answer (score 2):

I think The angular HttpInterceptor will only intercept requests that you make using HttpClient only provided by angular. It will not intercept any requests made in plain .js or jQuery

Comment: i have already mentioned that in question. do u have any hack ?

Comment: I can confirm that this is true. What is more HTTP_INTERCEPTOR works well with on module level, but each module may still have different HttpClient and then this would require multiple interceptors OR interceptor defined on app module level. Javascript http requests are not intercepted via angular interceptor...

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for intercepting calls made to Fetch API using Proxy.

```
window.fetch = new Proxy(window.fetch, {
    apply(target, thisArg, argsList) {
        //do your stuff;
        return target;
    },
});
```

Sample code for intercepting calls made through XMLHttpRequest using prototype.

```
(function(send) { 
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) { 
        //do your stuff;
        send.call(this, data);

    }; 
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23539487

Answer (score 0):

You can't intercept HTTP request in the UI. All HTTP requests pass through an active service worker. That is where you intercept the request, not in the UI.

Comment: Could you provide an example how this would be done?

Comment: I have an intro article to service workers. There is a section on service worker caching that should help.
https://love2dev.com/blog/what-is-a-service-worker/