# How to intercept oidc client js token call with Authorization code

Tags: axios, interceptor, oidc-client-js

I have a React application where I am using oidc-client.js for the login flow. I am using the code flow where I will first receive the authorisation code and with which I'll be fetching the token using the oidc client js. I need to pass an authorization header in the request made by the library, but the library doesn't support that. I need to intercept the request and add an authorization basic. I tried with axios interceptor but it's not getting intercepted. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

**Only if you couldn't find any better solution**: it is possible to intercept the XMLHttpRequest calls directly.

Here you can see how others are doing:
[Intercept XMLHttpRequest and modify responseText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959359/intercept-xmlhttprequest-and-modify-responsetext)