# Will axios Interceptors work for fetch calls as well?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I want to intercept all the AJAX calls in my app and am planning to use the below

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
  // `req` is the Axios request config, so you can modify
  // the `headers`.
  req.headers.someCustomHeader = 'XYZ';
  return req;
});
```

So basically, I want to set some custom header on all requests going out. But since in my app, I also have used fetch calls, not sure if the above would intercept only axios calls OR also intercept fetch() calls ?

Comment: You can test this by seeing if the fetch calls contain that custom header.
My bet is the fetch calls will not contain that header.

Comment: @GabrielLupu - yes, it does not contain that header...Not sure if there is a way to have one common intereceptor for both axios and fetch...That way, I have a common handling for both

Comment: Did you try monkey patching `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Nope....Any example for reference if you have?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959359/intercept-xmlhttprequest-and-modify-responsetext) out. patch the open method and then call the setRequestHeaders method.

Comment: Thanks...Seems like the example is for the response...I am looking to intercepting request...

Comment: Well, it seems `fetch` itself should be monkey patched. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425169/intercept-fetch-api-requests-and-responses-in-javascript)